# How to Use calc() to switch between color values?

Tags: css, css-variables, css-calc

Is it possible to use `calc()` function in CSS to manipulate hexadecimal color value?

In following CSS snippet I would like to use `--enable` variable to switch between two hexadecimal color values for `background-color` property of the **MyBtnStyle**: `--enable-color` and `--disable-color`.

It was possible to accomplish this when using `rgb(r,g,b)` color format where each color component was computed using `calc()`, but I would prefer to directly switch between hexadecimal color values.

```
    :root {
        --enable: 0;
        --disable-color: #ff0000;
        --disable-r: 255;
        --disable-g: 0;
        --disable-b: 0;
        --enable-color: #00ff00;
        --enable-r: 0;
        --enable-g: 255;
        --enable-b: 0;
    }

    .MyBtnStyle {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px;
        margin: 1px 1px;
        color: black;
        padding: 1px 1px;
        background-color: calc(var(--enable-color)*var(--enable) + var(--disable-color)*(1 - var(--enable))); 
    }

/* this works */
    /* rgb( calc(var(--enable-r)*var(--enable) + var(--disable-r)*(1 - var(--enable)) ), 
            calc(var(--enable-g)*var(--enable) + var(--disable-g)*(1 - var(--enable)) ), 
            calc(var(--enable-b)*var(--enable) + var(--disable-b)*(1 - var(--enable)) )) */
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot multiply hex values like You are doing. A trick is to use gradient and control the percentage of colors. This will work with any color format:

```css
:root {
  --enable: 0;
  --disable-color: red;
  --enable-color: #00ff00;
}

.MyBtnStyle {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  color: black;
  padding:20px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(
     var(--enable-color)  calc(100% * var(--enable)),
     var(--disable-color) 0
   );
     
 }
```

```html
<div class="MyBtnStyle" style="--enable:1">some text</div>

<div class="MyBtnStyle">some text</div>
```

Here is another syntax where you adjust the `background-size`:

```css
:root {
  --enable: 0;
  --disable-color: red;
  --enable-color: #00ff00;
}

.MyBtnStyle {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  color: black;
  padding:20px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(var(--enable-color) 0 0),
   var(--disable-color);
  background-size:100% calc(100% * var(--enable))
}
```

```html
<div class="MyBtnStyle" style="--enable:1">some text</div>

<div class="MyBtnStyle">some text</div>
```

Here is another idea [inspired from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59287516/8620333) where you can apply color to text or any other property and not only background. This trick works with `hsl()` coloration.

```css
:root {
  --enable: 0;
  --disable-color: red;
  --enable-color: #00ff00;
}

.MyBtnStyle {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  color: hsl(0,100%, calc((1 - var(--enable))*100%));
  border:3px solid hsl(120,100%, calc((1 - var(--enable))*50%));
  padding:20px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(var(--enable-color),var(--enable-color)),
   var(--disable-color);
  background-size:100% calc(100% * var(--enable))
}
```

```html
<div class="MyBtnStyle" style="--enable:1">some text</div>

<div class="MyBtnStyle">some text</div>
```

This can be useful in order to have full control on the contrast. We change the background color and the text color at the same time. It's easy between black and white colors (or two version of the same colors) since we have to only control the lightness.

To express any combination of two colors simply rely on the code in the question where we define `rgb()` colors

---

Another related question to get more tricks: [How to change the color of <div> Element depending on its height or width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56669587/8620333)

Comment: Oh that's so interesting! Yet another hack in my toolbox, and I'm glad I'm just a hobbyist so I don't have to worry too much about support and consistency when I'm the only party involved ^^

Answer (score 3):

[`color-mix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix) can be used to toggle between two colors.

In the below code, the `--toggle` variable is used to set `--color1` as the (default) background color, when `--toggle` is unset or is `0`, and if `--toggle` is set to `1` then `--color2` is used.

This works because `color-mix` is mixing the 2 colors, but at any given time, only one of them is being mixed at `100%` and is the dominant one.

(This method can work on with even more colors if the math is tinkered with a little bit)

```css
label {
  --color1: lightGreen;
  --color2: salmon;
  
  background: color-mix(in srgb, 
    var(--color1) calc(var(--toggle, 0) * 100%), 
    var(--color2) calc(100% - var(--toggle, 0) * 100%)
  );
  
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label:has(:checked) {
  --toggle: 1;
}
```

```html
<label><input type=checkbox hidden/></label>
```