# CSS: Can I select data value greater than?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div data-age="30">30</div>
```

Is there a way to have (PURE CSS) div in red when age<18 and in blue where age>18

Comment: No. A data attribute is a string not a value

Comment: You will have to incorporate JQuery or JavaScript. But it is not that difficult.

Comment: with CSS , you need a few selectors : example to start from: `div[data-age]/* + 1-9 */ {color:red}
div[data-age="19"],
div[data-age^="2"]/* 20's */
/* etc ... */
{color:initial}`

Comment: here is an example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zYGmYZo (click on the arrow at top right  where code stands then click on View compiled HTML or CSS to copy the html or css generated )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea based on [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56669800/8620333) where you can consider CSS variables:

```css
.box {
  font-size:30px;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:monospace;
  overflow:hidden;
  color:#fff;
  background:
     linear-gradient(red,red) 0 0/100% calc((18 - var(--a))*1px),
     blue;
}
.box:before {
  content:attr(style);
  text-indent:-4ch;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="--a:30" class="box"></div>
<div style="--a:18" class="box"></div>
<div style="--a:9 " class="box"></div>
<div style="--a:17" class="box"></div>
<div style="--a:0 " class="box"></div>
```

You can also do it for text coloration:

```css
.box {
  font-size:30px;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:monospace;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:5px solid transparent;
  background:
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) padding-box,
     linear-gradient(red,red) 0 0/100% calc((18 - var(--a))*1px),
     blue;
}
.box:before {
  content:attr(style);
  text-indent:-4ch;
  display:inline-block;
  color:transparent;
  background:
     linear-gradient(red,red) 0 0/100% calc((18 - var(--a))*1px),
     blue;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div style="--a:30" class="box"></div>
<div style="--a:18" class="box"></div>
<div style="--a:9 " class="box"></div>
<div style="--a:17" class="box"></div>
<div style="--a:0 " class="box"></div>
```