# In this mixin's @if statement, why won't this greater-than operator work?

Tags: html, css, sass

```
.container {
  --random: 200px;

  @mixin test() {
    @if (var(--random) > 500px) {
      color: orange;
    }
  }

  @include test();
}
```

What I want: if the variable is larger than 500px, style `.container` with `color: orange;`.

P.S. I wasn't sure how to make a code-snippet that to reproduce this error for you. Perhaps there's a website to make little SASS snippets you could suggest?

Comment: You can't use `var()` in `@if`. If you paste your code in https://www.sassmeister.com/ you'll get an undefined-operation error.

Comment: `--random` is a CSS Custom Property, not a SASS/SCSS variable.

Comment: @Dai Gutted. Thanks for the link. There's no SASS conditional logic that allows for CSS variables is there?

Comment: I think you need to understand how SCSS Variables work compared to CSS Custom Properties.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56669587/8620333 (what you want to do cannot be done with CSS variable or SASS, either JS or read the answer I linked)

Answer (score 1):

As Dai pointed out in the comments, there is a difference between [SASS variables](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables) and [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) (aka CSS variables). In your case, you should use a *SASS* variable:

```
.container {
  $random: 200px;

  @mixin test() {
    @if ($random > 500px) {
      color: orange;
    }
  }

  @include test();
}
```

Comment: Not possible to use a SASS variable in my case. I make a CSS variable that captures a certain element's width every-time the screen's resized. Have moved onto other solutions

Comment: Ah, then the condition couldn't work anyway since it exists only before the compilation.