# Setting background based on element aspect ratio in pure CSS

Tags: html, css

There is a `div` element and its size (both width and height) depends on its content. The content is loaded dynamically, so sometimes `div` width is greater than height and sometimes otherwise.

Is it possible to set different backgrounds in CSS for the case when `width > height` and for the case when `width < height` without JS?

I mean something like `orientation` media query, but for a given element, not the whole screen.

Comment: I think you will require JS for this...

Comment: Using js, Once the content received, you probably need to dynamically read the width & height of the element and set a class or style property accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For what I understand you want something like this:

```css
.box {
  min-height:50px;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid;
  background:
    linear-gradient(green,green)   left/calc(100% - 800px) 100%,
    linear-gradient(yellow,yellow) left/calc(100% - 600px) 100%,
    red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

So basically and in this specific case, if the DIV is more than 800px, the color will be green, between 600 and 800px yellow and less than 600px will be red.

Hope I helped.

Comment: copied from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56669800/8620333 and doesn't answer the question

Comment: Interesting trick, but I was looking for something more universal. Thank you anyway.